# Tabbed focus issues with Blueprint Dialog forms

Tags: blueprintjs

I've noticed sometimes the keyboard tabbing for focus gets messed up. In this case I am using a Blueprint Dialog component which contains a form to be submitted. The form is built with Redux Form wrapped Blueprint input components. When the dialog first opens I can tab to the concentration field of the form. The next two tabs focus hidden elements (see first image below). Then the "x" to close the dialog is focused, then the concentration field is focused again, and finally I can tab and focus the remaining fields and buttons.

Any tips on how to improve this? Its not clear to me why the pt-overlay-backdrop nor the pt-overlay-content would ever want to be tabbed into. I see they both have tabindex="0".. maybe that should be -1?

Thanks!

[image: hidden tabbed items]

[image: dialog]

Comment: https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/1166

Answer (score 1):

Set `Dialog`'s `autoFocus` to false can fix this issue.